# Как определить какая кнопка submit была нажата (используя только средства PHP)?

Tags: php, html, form

```
<html>
<body>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Введите имя человека</legend>
            <form method="POST">
                <div class="inner">
                    <input type="submit" name="all" value="Получить данные о всех людях в БД">
                    <div class="input-area">
                        <label for="name">Имя:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <input type="hidden" name="check" value="1">
                <input type="submit" name="specific" value="Получить данные о люядх с данным именем">
            </form>
        </fieldset>
        <a href="in.php" style="text-align: center">Записать данные в БД</a>  
        <?php
            require_once "../reg file/login.php";
            $con = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
            if ($con->connect_error) die("Сбой подключения к БД.");

            mysqli_query($con, "SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
            mysqli_query($con, "SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
            mysqli_query($con, "SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");

            if (isset($_POST["check"])) {
                if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                    die("Вы не ввели имя");
                }

                if (!empty($_POST["all"])) {
                    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM people");
                    if (!$stmt->excecute()) die("Fatal Error");
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                    echo "<h1>Данные о всех людях в БД:</h1>";
                }
                if (!empty($_POST["specific"])) {
                    $name = htmlentities($_POST["name"]);
                    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name=?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);                
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();

                    if ($stmt->affected_rows == 0) die("Людей с именем " . $name . " нет в базе");

                    echo "<h1>Данные о людях с именем $name:</h1>";

                }
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    echo "Возраст: " . $row["age"] . "<br>";
                    echo "Пол: " . ($row["gender"] == "male" ? "Мужской" : "Женский");
                }
                $stmt->close();

            }

            $con->close();

        ?>

    </body>
</html>
```

Я хочу понять какая именно кнопка была нажата.
Проверяю с помощью условий:

```
if (!empty($_POST["all"])) {
                    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM people");
                    if (!$stmt->excecute()) die("Fatal Error");
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();
                    echo "<h1>Данные о всех людях в БД:</h1>";
                }
                if (!empty($_POST["specific"])) {
                    $name = htmlentities($_POST["name"]);
                    $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM people WHERE name=?");
                    $stmt->bind_param("s", $name);                
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $result = $stmt->get_result();

                    if ($stmt->affected_rows == 0) die("Людей с именем " . $name . " нет в базе");

                    echo "<h1>Данные о людях с именем $name:</h1>";

                }
```

Но это не работает: какую бы кнопку я не нажимал срабатывает только вторая

**Как понять какая именно кнопка была нажата только средствами PHP/MySQL?**

**P.S.** Я видел похожие вопросы на SO, но ответа на свой вопрос я так и не нашел

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле всё оказалось куда проще!
Я просто-напросто ошибся в первом блоке if с написанием функции execute - случайно написал excecute. А "вы не ввели имя" выводилось потому, что я проверял было ли введено имя до того как входил в ветвь if (!empty($_POST["specific"])). Так что создавать  массив type и в нем элементы all и specific вообще не имеет смысла. Можно делать так, как я делал изначально

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="submit" name="type[all]" value="Получить данные о всех людях в БД">
// form data
<input type="submit" name="type[specific]" value="Получить данные о люядх с данным именем">
// some of your code
switch (array_keys($_POST['type'])[0]) :
    case 'all':
        // first scenario
        break;
    case 'specific':
        // second scenario
        break;
endswitch;
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку: Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

Comment: Я понял почему ошибку выдает - я не обратил внимания на type[all] и type[specific]. А что это значит? Впервые вижу такую конструкцию. Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить?

Comment: это группировка элементов формы под одним именем. в $_post записывается не отдельный элемент, а массив этих елементов. вы можете встретить эту запись повсеместно при использовании checkbox, например.

Comment: понятно, спасибо. А почему Вы в switch'e проверяете именно нулевой ключ массива type?

Comment: сперва достаю ключи, они сетятся как элементы массива (array_keys), и после обращаюсь к нулевому элементу этого массива. сделайте print_r($_POST), увидите, как приветают данные и почему так сделано

Comment: Я понимаю, что вы сделали) Мне не понятно почему вы берете именно нулевой ключ массива? Т. е. почему после отправки формы "all" или "specific" будет именно нулевым ключом в type? Разве в массиве type "all" и "specific" не станут автоматически 0 и 1 ключами?

Comment: нет (не совсем да). сделайте print_r($_POST) - вы всё поймёте.

Comment: Я понял почему вы проверяете именно нулевой элемент массива, сформированного array_keys(). При отправке формы в массиве type появляется только тот индекс и значение, которое было у того submita, на который я нажал

Comment: А значит и array_keys() вернет только один индекс, т.е. массив, состоящий из одного элемента

Answer (score 0):

Еще один способ как можно проверить это:

```
    <form action="" method="POST">
            <input type="submit" name="type[all]" value="Получить данные о всех людях в БД">
            <input type="submit" name="type[specific]" value="Получить данные о люядх с данным именем">
            <input type="hidden" name="check" value="1">
        </form>
        <?php
            if (isset($_POST["type"]["all"])) {
                //Одни действия
            }
            else if (isset($_POST["type"]["specific"])) {
                //Другие действия
            }
```